# How do I delete a segue in XCode storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, uistoryboardsegue, xcode-storyboard

At the moment, I have got two segues in my Storyboard. However, I need to delete one of the segues in the Storyboard. Is there any way to do this through the XCode storyboard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is there any way to do this through the XCode storyboard?

**Yes.** Click on the segue. Press the delete key.

Comment: Ha! So simple, so obvious. Thanks a million!!

Comment: If it was that simple you wouldn't have got 13 upvotes. For me it prompted me to delete the entire goddamned story board. XCode's crap.

Comment: I have the same thing as Siddharth.  Guess it's time to start my project over... there goes 2 hours.

Comment: @chodobaggins If you deleted the wrong thing, such as one of the scenes in the storyboard, you can always Undo the change. If you accidentally deleted the whole storyboard file, Xcode prompts you to decide whether to just remove the reference from the project (in which case you can just add it back again) or move the file to the trash (in which case you can move it from the trash back to your project folder and add it to the project again). I can't imagine why you'd need to start the project again.